Debian Bookworm always sets `COLUMNS` to be a little less than the actual terminal width
On Debian Bookworm, the $COLUMNS bash variable is always a little smaller than the actual terminal width. This leaves a little space on the right side whenever I run a program that runs through less, such as man, git help commit, etc. Here's a screenshot of the output of man bash, note the margin on the right side:

However, $COLUMNS on my Fedora is set to the full width of the terminal emulator.
How can I make the $COLUMNS variable always equal to the full width of the terminal emulator?
Since there are so many programs that would go through the pager, I prefer not using a solution that sets COLUMNS= before a particular program launches.
The solution should also be able to change $COLUMNS when the terminal window resizes, like what bash does by default.

I wonder if this really has anything to do with COLUMNS.  On my Debian machine, I also get the empty space on the right (which I like because shorter lines makes the text more readable), but COLUMNS is the full width of the terminal (and the same as the output from tput cols).  I instead think it has to do with some configuration of man on Debian, and changing that would be better than setting COLUMNS to something slightly wider than the terminal.

In my experience you do want at least one empty column at the right-hand side, to work around various bugs related to how lines wrap. More than two seems wrong, though.

You are not experiencing $COLUMNS being set (unless you set it yourself, but you haven't said so, and it doesn't happen by default) — you're experiencing man-db setting the width of the print-out to width - 2 if width <= 40 else floor(width * 39/40) which in your case works out to a good few columns missing.
I'd identified and fixed this in man-db !11, this is fixed in trixie (leaving only one free column due to groff < 1.23 tbl's tendency to spill 1 column for borders). In future this may be fixed to always use the whole teletype width.
You may want to work around this in bookworm by either backporting trixie man-db or putting something to the effect of
alias man='MANWIDTH=$(stty size | awk '\''{print int($2 * 40 / 39)}'\'') man'

in your shell's startup sequence, which will set $MANWIDTH to floor(width * 40/39) of your current teletype width, which should counter-act the scaling a bit.

Historically, the Unix man command delegated the choice of how wide to format a document completely to the typesetting programs nroff and troff.
For reasons that are, in my opinion, frustrating and stupid, nroff was never a termcap- or terminfo-based program.  In the 1970s it wrote output on the assumption that it was talking to a Teletype Corporation Model 37 by default.  However, if you checked the man page, you'd see that you could use its -T option to select other terminal types, including Diablo daisy-wheel printers.
All of these, every single one, was a hard-copy, paper-based device.
"Didn't people have video terminals back then?  Didn't the DEC VT100 come out around this time?  Hadn't the DEC VT52 been out for a while already even when Seventh Edition Unix was released in 1979?"
Yes, yes, and yes.  But for unclear reasons the Bell Labs CSRC that originated nroff and troff, and Unix itself, never had much enthusiasm for supporting "glass TTYs".  Perhaps like others in CS research, they'd seen or heard tell of Engelbart's "Mother of All Demos" in 1968, and were aware of Xerox PARC's successful prototype of the windows/icons/mouse/pointer (WIMP) UI that shortly became the dominant paradigm and remained so for decades, until the smartphone/mobile device era.  That certainly explains the group's focus in the 1980s on a workstation known successively--under increasing amounts of corporate pressure--as the "Jerq", the "Blit", and the "DMD 5620".  But that is a tale for another time.
The work of developing an abstraction layer for character-cell terminals fell to organizations like the Berkeley CSRG, which developed termcap.  Around this time, AT&T got the memo that they were going to be released from their 1956 consent decree with the U.S. government and would be permitted to sell computer hardware and software commercially.  As the U.S. telephone monopoly, they had been forbidden from much commercial activity outside of the telephone sector, despite having an enviable research lab that did a lot of innovative work in numerous fields.  ("Despite", I say, but this may be "because of".  If you don't have managers and investors insisting that every department be a profit center, and that every development be monetized, you can afford to do the sort of "pure research" that can reshape the market in your favor more than one financial quarter in the future.  But, you know, screw that.  Suits need money now for hookers and blow.)
So AT&T's Unix Support Group (USG) hired away the primary developer of BSD termcap, tasked him with writing a better, faster version--terminfo--stuck it into Unix System V, and slapped it with big warnings, "UNPUBLISHED PROPRIETARY SOURCE CODE OF AT&T."
Not long after the release of Seventh Edition Unix, Brian Kernighan refactored nroff and troff to make "device-independent troff".  Seventh Edition's troff could talk only to one sort of device, the C/A/T phototypesetter, a machine nearing the end of its marketable life.  Alternatives like the Autologic APS-5 and Mergenthaler Linotron 202 were the new hotness.  (And in just a few years, Adobe would introduce, and Apple would hugely popularize, PostScript.)
Sensing opportunity, AT&T thus also tried to monetize nroff and troff themselves, which were built from a common source base.  nroff, which produced terminal output, was largely neglected.  Nobody ever bothered to make AT&T nroff a program that knew anything about video terminals.  (When groff made its terminal output driver aware of video terminals by emitting a small set of ECMA-48 escape sequences that virtually every terminal emulator and console driver supports, people exploded in rage (or at least annoyance) because it broke assumptions that the less(1) pager program had been making.)  I've never heard anyone offer authoritative information on why AT&T never made nroff a terminfo application; my guess is that it was simply not regarded as commercially appealing and therefore not worth spending effort on, no matter how much sense it made.
And the Berkeley CSRG didn't refactor nroff around termcap because they lacked a license to post-V7 (device-independent) troff, which AT&T was now selling commercially (they called it DWB: "Documenter's Workbench"), and would continue to do so until about 1994 when an internal AT&T customer murdered the product by making a huge purchase of DWB licenses and then refusing to pay their bill, rendering its department insolvent.
The COLUMNS environment variable isn't magic; for it to have effect, an application has to use getenv() to collect its value and configure its output appropriately, or use a library that does so.
man-db man reads COLUMNS so that it can do essentially one thing: set a *roff register to tell the formatter (nroff, usually these days GNU nroff) what line length to use.  So COLUMNS=80 man ls becomes something like nroff -r LL=80n -m an /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.
But not exactly.  And thereby hangs a tale.  Yes, another one!
For over 20 years (counting from 1979, when the man(7) macro package was born in Seventh Edition Unix), the default line length in nroffs everywhere was 65n.  Meaning sixty-five "ens".  An "en" is a unit of measure employed by typographers.  But for our purposes we can say that one en equals one character cell in width.  When GNU/Linux and to a lesser extent the offspring of 4.4BSD-Lite experienced explosive growth in the 1990s, man page authors chafed at this limitation.  Everybody's console or terminal device, they said, was 80 columns wide--at least.  People were also using swank shizz like eterm (the "Enlightenment terminal emulator") with high-resolution, alpha-blended hentai stills as window backgrounds on their giant 21" Trinitron displays sporting 1280x1024 resolution and--watch out now--24 bits of color depth.  They also used really small fonts because they were young hackers who skipped college to accept payment mainly in stock options from dot-com startups, and nothing said you were cool like a giant terminal.  Your skill as a developer, you see, is directly correlated with how many character cells of source code you can fit on your screen.
At any rate, some of these bros occasionally had an attack of conscience and admitted that they read man pages.  A few even contributed to documentation, an unusual choice then and now.  They noticed that sometimes you wanted to use tbl to lay out a table and it looked weird to have your table stick out way to the right of your paragraphs (as long as you didn't overrun the 80 column width to which most terminal emulators, and, for many years, the Linux virtual console, defaulted).
So eventually, in 2002, the groff maintainer accommodated the changing preferences of the community, and increased the default line length in groff's "an-old.tmac" file (as it was then known) from 65n...but not quite to 80.  No, he stopped at 78n.
Why?
Because of bugs in GNU tbl when formatting for nroff, a.k.a. character cell devices.  Most of the bugs were predicated on a fundamental difference in the way rules (horizontal or vertical lines) and boxes (drawn with rules) were handled in tables.  On a typesetter, these rules are very thin (by default) and you can draw them between any character glyphs you want without having to shift the glyphs to make room.  So when you box a table, you do just that--you draw a box around it.
But when you box a table in a terminal, you have to redimension the table cells.  That's because each piece of horizontal rule -, vertical rule |, or intersection of these + takes up a character cell.  Any space you use for drawing these is space you can't use for the textual content of your table.
So let's say you have an unboxed tbl table that, when formatted on the terminal, is kissin' the 80 column limit.  It just fits.  One day you decide it would be nice if that table were boxed.  So you add the box option to it in your source document.
Now all of a sudden the table takes up 82 columns on the terminal and, if the terminal is not at least that wide, it looks like what is technically known as sh*t.  It overruns the line length, the remaining characters wrap to the next line, and it really is just horrible to look at.  It also tends to confuse the pager.  So it makes for a miserable reading experience.
Observing this, the groff maintainer reasoned at the time that it would suffice under most circumstances, for most man pages in other words, to just give tbl the extra 2 cells of width it sometimes needed for a boxed table (but didn't bother to update its internal computations to expect), by taking them away from everything else.  So 80n became 78n, and remained there.
Now it turns out, there are actually other ways, via features of tbl that are less often used, to make a table overrun.  Prior to groff 1.23.0 (2023), you could actually overrun the line length with vertical rules by an arbitrary amount.  Meaning, sometimes even a line length of 78n didn't leave you enough space.
In groff 1.23.0, some of those bugs in tbl were fixed, and in the forthcoming groff 1.24.0, the rest are.  As far as I know.  And the default line length in groff man(7) and mdoc(7) will, when formatting for terminals, be 80n.  Nowadays, with groff 1.23, if you take that same 80-column unboxed table and box it, one of a few things will happen.

If you use the expand table option, the gaps between table columns will shrink to accommodate the 2 cells now eaten up by the box sides.
If you use the x column option, the columns to which it applies will narrow by 2 cells  to accommodate the 2 cells now eaten up by the box sides.
If GNU tbl can't shrink the inter-column gaps (expand) or the column data itself, it won't--it gives up, oversets the line, and tells the formatter to throw a warning like table wider than line length minus indentation.  (tbl is a preprocessor; at the time it runs, it doesn't know what line length the output device will use.)

Also, in groff 1.24.0, grotty, the output driver for terminal devices (and therefore a program that runs pretty much every time you use man(1)), may become a terminfo application at long last.  We'll see if that lands in time.
